# Javascript: How do I use React component globally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx

I've made an NPM package for react, it's working fine on Node but it's not working on browser without node.

if I import within node like this:

```
import Progress from 'package-name'

// jsx
<Progress /> //working fine
```

It's working fine.

But if I use it from CDN like unpkg, it's not working.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>

// Package Script
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@delowar/react-circle-progressbar@0.0.9/lib/Progress.js"></script>

<script>
    ...react code...
    <Progress />
    ...react code...
</script>
```

It's showing an error:

> Progress is not defined

[image]
Can anyone please help me about this issue?

**Webpack Configuration:**

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/Progress.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('lib'),
        filename: 'Progress.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        library: 'lib',
        umdNamedDefine: true,
        globalObject: `(typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this)`
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Original Repo: https://github.com/delowardev/react-circle-progressbar

Comment: can you post content of progress.js

Comment: Build version: https://github.com/delowardev/react-circle-progressbar/blob/dev/lib/Progress.js

Comment: Source: https://github.com/delowardev/react-circle-progressbar/blob/dev/src/Progress.js

Comment: Does not look like your JS file is exporting any member called Progress.

Comment: @jaibatrik Can you please tell me can I do that?

Comment: I think it might be related to how you are building with Webpack. Check different output targets in Webpack configurations. I think you can directly export the ES6 module / file as is, that should work with browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the value of `library` to the name of your component `library: 'Progress'` and add `libraryExport: 'default'` to assign the default export to the library target:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve('lib'),
  filename: 'Progress.js',
  library: 'Progress',
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
  libraryExport: 'default',
  umdNamedDefine: true,
  globalObject: `(typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this)`
},
```

**Working example**:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Progress />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/fraction01/react-circle-progressbar/0957fed54db16a3f7b9d625711ed3961f3b34371/lib/Progress.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should configure it as external dependency as described in the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/).
Add this to your webpack configuration:

```
externals : {
    Progress: 'progress'
}
```

Usage:
`import Progress from 'progress';`

Answer (score 0):

You can't require or import modules directly from URL.

But you can import it like below.

```
// Package Script
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@delowar/react-circle-progressbar@0.0.9/lib/Progress.js"></script>

const Progress = window.Progress;
```